# D3 Pack enclose not working

Tags: d3.js

I am using D3's pack(root) method. That method will at some point call the packEnclose method which is not working. Can someone explain how that method works.

The function seems to be working most of the time but when I give it some different data it will sometimes not work.

Below is a code sample of how I call D3 pack

```
var stratify = d3.stratify()
    .parentId(function(d) { 
        return d.id.substring(0, d.id.lastIndexOf("@")); });

var root = stratify(data)
        .sum(function(d) { return d.value; })
        .sort(function(a, b) { return (a.value - b.value) })
    //  .eachAfter(function(node) { node.value = node.data.value;})

var pack = d3.pack()
    .size([width - margin, height - margin])
    .padding(5);
pack(root);
```

I have tried enough and I am sure the only difference between a working example and a failing example are the values themselves. If you want to test out I could send you the data arrays, because I cannot attach them to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never figured this out but found a weird way of fixing the issue. After investigating the difference between the data that worked and the data that didn't I found there was a difference. The data that did not work looked like it was full of integers after writing it to another file, while the data that worked looked like a bunch of floats. Even though I explicitly put parseFloat in my code so both should be floats.

Anyway I just added 0.01 (not 0.000000001 as that would not work for some reason) to every single data point. For some reason this is working and has not cause any problems yet.